# Better Performance: WMI vs SNMP?

Tags: java, windows, wmi, snmp

What has better performance under Windows for retrieving stats like CPU/Memory/Disk usage, etc.? WMI or SNMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this paper](http://www.scribd.com/doc/12810955/Network-Management-Paper-SNMP-vs-WMI) by Berry Hoekstra:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> A paper I wrote about the differences
>   of SNMP and WMI. I discuss both
>   monitoring standards and conclude if
>   WMI is really necessary in a world
>   where SNMP is king.